# how to change the activity type of an email activity

Tags: administration, activities, configuration

When I send an email form within an object* in Salesforce, an associated `activity` is created. The "type" of the activity is recorded as call. How can configure Salesforce so that some other value is set in stead by default.
*=Case, for example.

Comment: I also want to be able to edit the default "type" for a particular task record type. - Answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you check the values of **Type** field in Task and make sure that the "Call" value isn't selected as default for sending emails ?

Comment: how would you suggest checking the value?

Comment: Go to Setup --> Customize --> Activities -->
Task Fields --> Type
and check if the Call value is selected as default for Send Email

Comment: Thanks for your help. I see now that you can change the default type for each record type. Setup | Customise | Activities | Task Record Types | Select the record type you need to modify and then select Edit "Type" field from the Picklist Available for Editing and change the default from the drop down.